# XY to Line tool 'Failure to execute'

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I wish to generate a road with approximately 1090 XY coordinates, my only problem is that my XY to line tool will not execute, i get this message 'Error 999999: error executing function. Failure to execute (XY To Line).' what could the problem be?

Comment: What is your input format? How is your data structured? What version of ArcGIS do you use? What are your input parameters? A sample of your data and a screenshot of the tool's interface with parameters or anything equivalent would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am putting a screen shot of my model and input data up now.

Comment: @GISGe it will not let me post pictures as i do not have sufficient reputation, I use ArcGIS 10.1 desktop, My input format is from an excel spread sheet, The model had no problem running an input of about 10 or so pieces of data but as soon as I tried to run anything more than 50 the error appeared, The tool is what seems to be the problem, As it was working fine dealing with 0-20 pieces of data but now after trying to use a much larger portion of data the Tool will no longer run small amounts of data, I am wondering if the tool could have been damaged,and if there is another tool I could use.

Comment: Without seeing the data it's difficult to know what's wrong. Could you upload your excel sheet to dropbox or any similar site so we can access it and try to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @GISGe  have Google drive, Here is the Link to the spread sheet https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4_TJdssPL1Rd2JlQ25oSFBfSHc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It's a bit hard to read your screenshot, maybe you can upload a high-res version and link to it? Also, your error message is a generic one. It doesn't really say anything at all, and from that alone there's no way to tell what could be the problem. I suggest you try to run parts of your model to find where the problem occurs. From that you can probably work out what could be the issue. If not, you can post a question again here with a more specific problem description (which I realize you don't have now).

Comment: You can also use copy/paste from the tool results window to get the error into your Question in a readable and searchable form.  There is an edit button beneath your Question to do the editing.  Also include the version of ArcGIS for Desktop you are using, and what happens when you run the XY To Line tool manually on the same input data?

Comment: I get the same error message as you do, but the output is created anyway. Is it still the case for you?

Comment: @PolyGeo  thank you both for the feedback i will edit my question and make it more descriptive.

Comment: My goal is to get 3 KML files out of the model, The Points, A line connecting the Points, and a buffer around the line, were you able to get all 3? @GISGe

Comment: I'm just running the XY to Line tool, I don't have access to your model.

Comment: true that, i apologize, so was the line actually generated? @GISGe

Comment: at first I would check that the coordinate system is OK

Comment: @radouxju I have checked that it is okay and it was running Excel spreadsheets with less data, But, of the same format as my actual spread sheet containing the data collected for the road, but, straight after i tried to run the excel spreadsheet containing my Road data and received the error message for the first time, now it will not even run small amounts of data in the same format. I am going to reinstall ArcGIS desktop 10.1 and see if the problem is resolved.

Comment: Another issue I got with this tool is that it does not accept Fields in your Excel sheet or CSV that have spaces or special characters. Thought I'd contribute that since that stopped me from being able to use the tool successfully for a long time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last record (594th row at line 595) doesn't have from & to XY coordinates, that is why the tool creates the first 593 lines but returns an error when trying to convert the 594th.
Also, ArcGIS might read the next empty lines in the excel sheet as rows (if you preview the excel sheet in ArcGIS, you see there are more than 1000 rows).
You should

1. Convert the excel sheet to a geodatabase or dbf table
2. Add coordinates at line 595
3. Remove the empty lines.

Then the tool runs fine and doesn't return an error message, so your model will not be interrupted anymore.

[image]

Comment: that worked! thank you so much its been driving me crazy!

Comment: Glad I could help you :)